# Plotting a cumulative sum with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm missing something really obvious or simply doing this wrong. I have two dataframes of similar structure and I'm trying to plot a time-series of the cumulative sum of one column from both. The dataframes are indexed by date:

```
df1
              value
2020-01-01    2435
2020-01-02    12847
...
2020-10-01    34751
```

The plot should be grouped by month and be a cumulative sum of the whole time range. I've tried:

```
line1 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).value.cumsum()
line2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).value.cumsum()
```

and then plot, but it resets after each month. How can I change this?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order by first adding another column to your df with the cumsum of value and then using ```pd.Grouper``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to group and take the mean or something to represent the cumulative value for each month, and plot:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randint(100,200,366)},
                   index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/1/2019'))

df1.cumsum().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).mean().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! guess it's not the idea of this forum to have people guessing what you're trying to do, but it worked :)